# Spacewar on microcontroller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, vga

First of all I need to say that I have almost no experience with programming microcontrollers (aside for some Arduino stuff). I have worked with C (and x86 ASM) on some low level projects (think of kernel stuff, embedded systems) so I think the software part should not be an issue.

Since I'm trying to learn something about microcontrollers I figured the best way to do it is to take a pet project. I made up my mind and I want to implement [Spacewar!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacewar!) on a microcontroller. If it was able to run on a PDP1 in the 60's should run on a microcontroller (I think).

So here's my question, could you recommend any particular development board that would have a VGA port for me to display (just black/white) the game. I am planning to use a usb keyboard for the controls.

Would the VGA displaying (i need only b/w, 640x480 would be more than enough, I would go for even less) be out of the reach for a cheap board (<=100$)?

Any recommendations for the board? Any other issues you think I might encounter?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your aim to make a faithful copy of Spacewar! or to learn about driving a VGA display?

Comment: faithful copy of Spacewar!, but I'm trying to learn as much as possible so VGA would be nice. Alternatively I could use other methods to send the data to my laptop and from there simulate a display, but that wouldn't be as cool :)

Comment: I defer to Leon Heller on this one, but on a few occasions he has mentioned the Parallax Propeller.  Well, I got a screaming deal on their development board, and it has a VGA port built-in.  From the videos I've seen, I would not be surprised if they make sending video signals very easy.  Check it out!

Comment: If you go for propeller, do note that it's much easier to interface PS/2 keyboards and mice to it than USB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hackvision is essentially an Arduino designed for retro game development.  You program it with ordinary Arduino IDE, and it uses the TVout library.

TVout is an Arduino library that makes it easy to generate low-res monochrome composite video for a TV. I designed Hackvision which is essentially an Arduino board and game controller combined, and it has audio/video outputs that you connect to your TV. TVout, my controllers library, and game examples make it easy to start writing your own games. And the since the games are written with the normal Arduino IDE, it's fine for beginners. Hackvision would be useful to the original poster because all the hardware is taken care of, and Arduino coding is widely understood.

[http://nootropicdesign.com/hackvision/](http://nootropicdesign.com/hackvision)

Comment: can you give us more technical details of what you have done. It sounds interesting but my goal is to always avoid answers that need the other site to know the details, albeit that without your site your product would not be available, bringing a different bag of worms.

Comment: edit it in, make your answer more thorough and complete!

Comment: As far as my needs go, this is the answer I was hoping for. Great work, this should be so much fuun :D. The price range is great, it's arduino so it's *nix friendly, the examples look soooo cool, I'm sorry I can only upvote your answer once.

Comment: whoa.  this is bad.  not bad meaning bad, but bad meaning good.

Answer (score 8):

One MCU that should be suitable for implementing Spacewar is the 32-bit eight-core [Parallax Propeller](http://www.parallax.com/tabid/407/Default.aspx), as each core has a video and VGA interface. What appear to be equally complex games have been ported to it.

I remember playing Spacewar on a DEC PDP-12 where I once worked, many years ago.

Comment: the more posts I read from you about this micro, the more I'm dying to use my dev kit.  Parallax recently had them on sale for $119!  Are you using ViewPort?

Comment: Hell, don't bother with the dev-kit, just buy a protoboard and a prop-clip (or a USB proto-board) - That's like $50

Comment: Or, buy one of the new $20 QuickStart kits. They are out of stock at the moment. though. I got two of them. I don't use ViewPort.

Answer (score 4):

If you **already have Arduino board**, then you can use some **TV out library** like **[this](http://www.batsocks.co.uk/products/Shields/TellyMate%20Shield.htm)**,  **[this](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/TVout)**, or **[this](http://nootropicdesign.com/ve/projects.html)**. As you can see you can also order or make your self these cheap boards.

Comment: can you give me a bit more detail about why the tv out library is great?

Comment: I think that generating video signal in pure software with exact timing without external video chip is fascinating and I like it. It has it's use. If you google around, you will see that color is also achieved this way, and with external ram it's not just a color bar but real TV or VGA character and graphics generator. Another fascinating AVR usage is USB device in pure software.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to an analog scope, I'd suggest wiring a microcontroller with a couple DACs to the XY of the scope.  If you can control the Z (brightness) as well, that would be even better; otherwise if your DACs are fast enough you can simply let the beam dwell on the points that are supposed to be lit.

Comment: [Spacewar! on oscilloscope](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Spacewar!_Oscilloscope_Game_(MSP430%29)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt necessarily call a board that has a video interface a microcontroller.  I dont (yet) know enough about how spacewar interfaced to the display, you could try an asteroids approach where the program created a list of instructions for the vector graphics engine which itself was a processor of sorts with instructions and subroutine calls, etc.  Periodically send a list of video instructions across a serial port to a host, like a dumb terminal, that displays the video.

Another approach might be to just get a gameboy advance, 16mhz ARM7, has a display, has pushbuttons.  Cost about $\$$30 or $\$$40 on ebay.  At places like realhotstuff.com you can get a flash cartridge or easier to use an sd (mini, micro or full size) card based one.  Shop around some are harder to use than others.  I also recommend getting a game link cable only so that you can cut it and make two serial cables, use something like this perhaps

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/718

or this is the one I normally use

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/449

Write a bootloader and have it boot off the cartridge, then you can download programs via serial into ram and run them there, saves enormous amounts of time pulling the cartridge out then the sd card then mounting it copying the new file, unmount put it in the cartridge cartridge in the gba boot and wait, fail, start again.  With the serial bootloader you can off and on or follow the devr's page instructions and add a reset button.

Probably worth spending just a few bucks more and using a gba sp.  You get a backlit display and a power cord to leave it plugged in all the time.  An NDS will work from a cartridge and developers perspective but is more painful than the GBA for getting your feet wet.  yes in both cases you can simply fall into one of the existing sandboxes and really learn nothing about the embedded part of it.  I wouldnt bother doing anything embedded in that case just write an app on your computer and be done with it.

If you dont like the gba path you might consider a microcontroller and buy a display separately, earthlcd or sparkfun or someplace like that, easy to come by.  The oled on the stellaris eval boards is probably too small, but oled would be really cool.  You might also look at some of the fpga boards, they often have things like vga ports or lcd control, etc and you can put a mico8 or microblaze or other processor in there.  A bigger project than just writing software for an eval board yes, but puts you in the category of a microcontroller with a vga port.

I have not looked at the details but adding something like this to some other microcontroller board may give you the package you are looking for

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10329

Or perhaps a stellaris board with usb otg, and get some sort of usb based video driver.

What are you using as your baseline source?  Having done a static binary translation of asteroids myself, first an emulation then a translation from the pdp1 sources/binary sounds like a very fun project.

Comment: if you have an nds laying around and get a gba, I highly recommend the ez flash 3 in 1, make sure it is the GBA sized.  To get started you can program it initially on the nds (well you need a slot 1 cartridge for that too, any will do there are lots of $20 ones), then once you have a bootloader you can re-program it from the gba, the company has an open source library for performing these tasks.